# summation of $ \tan A + \tan (A+B)+....\tan(A+(n-1)B)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

what will be the  result of following $ \tan A + \tan (A+B)+....\tan(A+(n-1)B)$?
 solve the summation of series?
what is the way to solve to series problem?
step to follow the series ?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro. I don't they there is a formula for tan. Why do you think that there is a formula for this?

Comment: @user600016. There is a formula for that. The problem is that it involves the digamma function.

Comment: Have fun with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BTan%5BA+%2B+i+B%5D%2C+%7Bi%2C+0%2C+n+-+1%7D%5D

Comment: I would certainly not call that a formula :)